# How to solve " C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe: can't open file " error?

Tags: python, msys2, msys

I am getting error when I want to run my python script in terminal which says...

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe: can't open file
```

Possible Problem Cause:

I have installed **MSYS2** in my machine so that I can use `g++` and `gcc` compilers for C/C++ Programs and to use `g++` and `gcc` I needed to add `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` path to system environment variables.

`C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` folder has python.exe in it; so I am guessing that it is causing some kind of collision between my python interpreter and `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`'s python.exe

When I remove `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` path from system Environment variables, I am getting expected output.

**What do I want?**

I want a solution in which I can keep using both, python and g++/gcc.

Comment: Can you reorder the PATH components so that your default Python interpreter comes up first?

Comment: This is a great IDEA. Actually I tried to reorder paths but I had `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` in system Environmental Variables and Actual python interpreter path in User's Environmental Variables so , I was unable to achieve my goal.
But Now I have shifted both the path to User's Environmental Variables so It's working now...
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reordered paths in System/User's environmental variables and now I am getting what I needed.